# How many users on Mi Yodeya are actually Jewish? Orthodox?

Tags: discussion

As I've been using the website I've come across many users who either from their pictures or from context don't seem Jewish. Just curious how any users are actually Jewish? Orthodox? And if not, then how and why did you get on this website? I'm sure their are many interesting stories... do share!

Comment: The question, as asked in the title, cannot be answered since membership is anonymous and no statistics like these are collected. If you want stories, you should reflect this better in the tile of your question

Answer (score 3):

I am Jewish. I disagree with the common presumption that subcategorization by "movement" is an essential aspect of Jewish identity and prefer not to define myself by affiliation with any such movement, but rather with the same verse cited [by Rabbi Kaii](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5505/). That said, given my institutional associations and pattern of attempted observance, those who insist on such categorization would naturally mark me as "Orthodox." I initially encountered this community by founding it.

I take exception to the implication that I perceive in the use of the word "actually" in the question, that Mi Yodeya is an Orthodox Jewish community. Mi Yodeya, per our [official tagline](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour), is "for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more." As such, the core community of experts we're targeting would mostly consist of what I'd call "observant Jews." ("Mostly" because the definition would squarely fit observant Noahides as well.) While there is a high correlation between this category and what people call "Orthodox," Mi Yodeya is [not an Orthodox community](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Orthodox+is%3Aquestion) by affiliation or by definition.

Comment: Indeed, qualifying the term Jew is silly, what is better or needs improving on the title Jew. There were no Orthodox, Conservative, Reform or Secular Jews at Sinai, I'll bet

Answer (score 2):

> עִבְרִי אָנֹכִי וְאֶת יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם אֲנִי יָרֵא ([יונה א׃ט](https://www.sefaria.org/Jonah.1.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he))

> [I'm a Jew and I'm proud, and I sing it out loud because (forever and ever) Hashem is watching over me!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aii3fDdZnrM&ab_channel=BennyFriedman)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a conservative Jew with a slightly orthodox leaning, and happened upon here when looking around for a halakha question completely by accident. I liked it and since found myself with the odd question or two.